# Can I apply two shaded color on single image with image filter in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have two shaded colors like this:

[image: with color red and blue]

I want to apply gradient colors on  single image with fabric js image filter.

Basically I added two palettes for colors. What I need is when I change color from palettes that both colors apply in a single image like the above image. Is that possible?

I am designing a T-shirt like below:

[image: The t-shirt]

I want to apply those two colors on a big grey image of the T-shirt. Currently different color images are working as separate image and separate object in fabric js and I want to apply those colors on single grey image part.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [FabricJs](http://fabricjs.com/) doesn't give natively the possibility of apply a gradient to an `Image`, you can achieve your task with the `ImageFilter` included in the following code snippet.

```js
(function(global) {

      'use strict';

      var fabric = global.fabric || (global.fabric = {}),
        extend = fabric.util.object.extend;

      fabric.Image.filters.GradientEffect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter, {

        type: 'GradientEffect',

        initialize: function (options) {
          options = options || {};
          this.gradient = options.gradient || {};
          this.img = options.img;
        },

        applyTo: function(canvasEl) {
          var gr = this.gradient;
          var w = this.img._element.naturalWidth;
          var h = this.img._element.naturalHeight;
          var hc = document.createElement('canvas');

          hc.setAttribute('width', w);
          hc.setAttribute('height', h);

          var fhc = new fabric.Canvas(hc);
          var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            fill: 'transparent',
            width: w,
            height: h
          });

          rect.setGradient('fill', gr);

          fhc.add(rect);
          fhc.renderAll();

          var ifhcContext = fhc.getContext('2d');
          var fhcImageData = ifhcContext.getImageData(0, 0, fhc.width, fhc.height);
          var fhcData = fhcImageData.data;

          var context = canvasEl.getContext('2d'),
            imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height),
            data = imageData.data;

          for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
            if(data[i] != 0 && data[i+1] != 0 && data[i+2] != 0) {
              data[i] += fhcData[i];
              data[i + 1] += fhcData[i + 1];
              data[i + 2] += fhcData[i + 2];

            }
          }

          context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
        },

        toObject: function() {
          return extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
            gradient: this.gradient

          });
        }
      });

      fabric.Image.filters.GradientEffect.fromObject = function(object) {
        return new fabric.Image.filters.GradientEffect(object);
      };

    })(typeof exports !== 'undefined' ? exports : this);


var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

fabric.Image.fromURL('http://i.imgur.com/bkMw5mx.png', function(img) {
  var gr = {
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 0,
    y2: img.height,
    colorStops: {
      0: "red",
      1: "blue",
    }
  };
  img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.GradientEffect({
    gradient: gr,
    img: img,
    
  }));
  img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
  canvas.add(img.set({
    width: 150,
    height: 150,

  }));
}, {
  crossOrigin: ''
});
```

```css
.floatLeft {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.placeholder {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<img class='image floatLeft' src='http://i.imgur.com/bkMw5mx.png' width='200' height='200'>
<div class='placeholder floatLeft'>
  <canvas id='c' width='300' height='300'></canvas>
  <div>
```

---

The work is done by applyTo function, I create a new `Canvas` on the fly and I put a rectangle filled with the argument gradient on it, then, pixel by pixel, I apply the relative color picked from the gradient. <strike>The only problem is that your image couldn't be resized on the fly, because the `imageData` of the image and the `imageData` of the gradient should be of the same lenght</strike>:

```
applyTo: function(canvasEl) {
          var gr = this.gradient;
          var w = this.img._element.naturalWidth;
          var h = this.img._element.naturalHeight;
          var hc = document.createElement('canvas');

          hc.setAttribute('width', w);
          hc.setAttribute('height', h);

          var fhc = new fabric.Canvas(hc);
          var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            fill: 'transparent',
            width: w,
            height: h
          });

          rect.setGradient('fill', gr);

          fhc.add(rect);
          fhc.renderAll();

          var ifhcContext = fhc.getContext('2d');
          var fhcImageData = ifhcContext.getImageData(0, 0, fhc.width, fhc.height);
          var fhcData = fhcImageData.data;

          var context = canvasEl.getContext('2d'),
            imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height),
            data = imageData.data;

          for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
            if(data[i] != 0 && data[i+1] != 0 && data[i+2] != 0) {
              data[i] += fhcData[i];
              data[i + 1] += fhcData[i + 1];
              data[i + 2] += fhcData[i + 2];

            }
          }

          context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
        }
```

Comment: when i use your code with my sample T-shirt i applied RED and GREEN color but its showing like red and yellow gradient effact. am i missing something ? fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/dDUC3/3201/

Comment: I was improved my code a bit, btw look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/yb3w28u6/, with my sample work like a charm, seems related to your image sample(too many white. I think), try with a darken sample, good luck!